# PHP curl module not recognised

Tags: server, 18.04, php, nginx, mariadb

I am installing https://github.com/pH7Software/pH7-Social-Dating-CMS

On a virgin Ubuntu 18.04 server.

I am going by [this guide](https://websiteforstudents.com/configure-ph7cms-ph7-builder-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-with-nginx-mariadb-and-php-7-2-fpm/)

Nginx, php 7.3 (Maria DB).

It all went well, the installation script asked for various PHP modules, I installed them all via apt.

But, the final module, curl.  I have it installed.  It is definitely there.  it is listed as a PHP module, but the script cannot see it.

Still keeps asking for the module and refuses to continue with the installation.

I installed it before using PHP and Apache, I suspect the issue may be Maria and/or Nginx.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What command did you use to install the curl module? Have you enabled the module in the configuration of PHP? What does a page with [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) show?

Comment: sudo apt install php7.2-curl  Same way I installed all the mother modules.  phpinfo() shows cURL module, author Sterling Hughes .

Comment: Does the script you're using produce an error message?

Comment: You have 1 error(s):
1) Please install "cURL" PHP extension.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
sudo apt install php7.3-curl curl

service nginx restart && sevice php7.3-fpm restart
```